# Detecting altered web Api

Tags: security, grails

Is it possible to detect that the http call or web api is altered in between the client & server by some attacker ?
Few days ago I was just analysing the network by "Hangout" iOS app using burp , & it just amazed me .
The app & server both is able to detect that I have changed the original call.
App shows "message sending failed" , without even getting any server response.
I want to built something similar in grails .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to implement something similar to this would be to "fingerprint" each request by hashing it with a known salt. Then comparing the provided hash value with the hashed value computed on the server. Obviously rejecting the request if the values don't match (indicating that the request was altered).

The problem you are going to face is that, unlike the iOS application, a Grails application is delivered in a web browser. As such, any processing you do (hashing the request with the salt) is going to be easily readable and thus worthless.

However, this "fingerprinting" would work very well for server to server communication via REST/HTTP API.